# Read and parse values from xml file using python

Tags: python, xml

I am struggling with reading xml file in python. The file format is somewhat weird:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<root>
<document> 
<field   level = "system" name = "Document ID" value = "1"/>
<field   level = "system" name = "Image count in document" value = "2"/>
<field   level = "system" name = "Page count in document" value = "1"/>
<field   level = "document" name = "barcode" value = "K0000001"/>
<field   level = "system" name = "Document Filename" value = "K0000001.pdf"/>
<field   level = "system" name = "Output date &amp; time" value = "2018.11.22 08:00:15"/>
</document> 
</root>
```

I need to read and pass specific values from this file, value for barcode and value for date and time. It's the first time I come across such xml format. All the XML tutorials states that you should not end up with xml formatted in this way but they do not say what to do when you do...

Comment: I don't see anything "weird" about that xml.

Comment: The XML is odd only in that it uses *attributes* rather than *elements* to store the information for each field which is a completely permissible way to format the XML.  Please show what you've tried to read the attributes and we should be able to help more.

Answer (score 0):

I was not familiar with such XML format, after some more research I got it right with:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
d = {}
e = ET.parse('filepath')
    root = e.getroot()
    for field in root.findall('document'):
        for line in field:
            account_d[line.attrib['name']] = line.attrib['value']
print(d)
```

Thanks, for comments, I will search more deeply next time ;)